# Sample from matrix and record matrix index in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a two column matrix of the following form:

```
 1.   1  1 
 2.   1  1
 3.   1  2
 4.   1  2
 5.   2  2
 6.   2  2
 7.   3  2
 8.   3  2
 9.   3  3 
 10.  4  3
 11.  4  4
```

I would like to sample a single number from the first column using say randsample().

Let's say the results is 2.

What I would like to know is which ROW was the sample taken from? (in this case it could have been sampled both from row 5 or row 6)

Is this possible?

Comment: and why don't you get a random number from 1 to 11, and use that as index for getting the value from your first column of the matrix?

Answer (score 3):

It's easy with `find` and `==`:

```
>> A = [
    1  1
    1  1
    1  2
    1  2
    2  2
    2  2
    3  2
    3  2
    3  3
    4  3
    4  4];

>> R = randsample(4,1)
>> find(A(:,1) == R)

R =
     4
ans =
    10
    11
```

Or, as indicated by igor milla,

```
>> I = randi(11)
>> A(I, :)

I =
     9
ans =
     3     3
```

Comment: I would sample indices, or keep the logical indices thus avoiding find unoess strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to sample one value, the solution as given by @igor milla is fine. But if you want to use the options given by `randsample` then I would recommend you to sample the column numbers rather than the sample directly.

```
A = rand(11,2); %suppose this is your matrix
k = 1; %This is the size of your desired sample
mysampleid = randsample(size(A,1),k)
mysample = A(mysampleid,:)
```

Now `mysampleid` contains the numbers of the columns, and mysample contains the rows that you sampled.
If you just want to sample the first column you can use `A(mysampleid,1)` instead.